# HTML if url present export as href link

Tags: html, wordpress

I"m working on a wordpress site and I don't have much experience with php. On wordpress you can enter a url for the site. I need help with creating an if statement as if a url is present the links to the url entered in on wordpress.

How does it works in wordpress when a user can input a url on different icons. If they do the icon needs to be clickable like href.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="legend">
    <div class="text-center">

    <p>As we continue to track performance and goal achievement, TBD spaces will be filled in with <br />content meant to support and react to continuing progress and opportunities.</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="oem-event"><span>OEM Event</span></li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Research</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Audit</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Planning</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-car" aria-hidden="true"></i> Inventory</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-commenting" aria-hidden="true"></i> Blog</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i> Comparison</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sitelink</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-window-maximize" aria-hidden="true"></i> Landing Page</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Custom</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Social Post</li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i> Migration </li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class= "fa fa-font-awesome" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enhancement </li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class="fa fa-certificate" aria-hidden="true"></i> WOW </li>
            <li class="fa-icon"><i class= "fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i>Google Post</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this so far:

```
<?php

    // The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

    // The Text you want to filter for urls
    $text = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com";

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {

       // make the urls hyper links
       echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href="{$url[0]}">{$url[0]}</a> ", $text);

    } else {

       // if no urls in the text just return the text
       echo $text;

    }
?>
```

However I don't think this is the right thing for what I need to do

Comment: You won't get the answer you are asking for on Stackoverflow if you don't provide us more information about what you have tried so far. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order on how to write a fully qualified question.

Comment: You cloud asked this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want more clearly? I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do at all.

Comment: So the site works where you can add a url for the icons above. But there are times where you don't need them so I need help with adjusting the code above so if there is a url the <li> is a href link